# NullPointerException after adding Summary Row Layer in Nattable

Tags: nullpointerexception, eclipse-rcp, nattable

We are Updating Nattable  version to 2.0.2 from 1.6.0.

We are getting **NPE** in **RowIdHideShowLayer** when we are fetching the **ILayerCell#getConfigLabels()**.

It happens only **when we add summary Row Layer**, otherwise it works fine.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:347) 
    at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:232) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.hideshow.RowIdHideShowLayer.isRowIndexHidden(RowIdHideShowLayer.java:191) ~
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.hideshow.RowIdHideShowLayer.getConfigLabelsByPosition(RowIdHideShowLayer.java:171) ~
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractIndexLayerTransform.getConfigLabelsByPosition(AbstractIndexLayerTransform.java:345) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.SelectionLayer.getConfigLabelsByPosition(SelectionLayer.java:581) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayerTransform.getConfigLabelsByPosition(AbstractLayerTransform.java:341) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.CompositeLayer.getConfigLabelsByPosition(CompositeLayer.java:593) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayerTransform.getConfigLabelsByPosition(AbstractLayerTransform.java:341) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.CompositeLayer.getConfigLabelsByPosition(CompositeLayer.java:593) 
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.cell.AbstractLayerCell.getConfigLabels(AbstractLayerCell.java:55)
```

How do we fix it ?

[NPE in RowIdHideShowLayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHIhf.jpg)

Comment: First, there is no version 2.2.0, I suppose you mean 2.0.2. Second I can't help without further details. How and where do you add the summary row layer to your layer composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `RowIdHideShowLayer`. You can fix this by locally overriding `isRowIndexHidden(int)` and adding a null check.

The fix in NatTable is handled here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=580072